# Place slideshow under parent DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, slideshow

I'm trying to place a carousel within the border of this`div`, I've tried `z-index` on the carousel which did work but it made all of the other items within it not clickable.

I have tried setting the border radius of another wrapper to match but this for some reason doesn't do anything. Is there a way to place it behind the `div` that's solely a border so that the edges don't overlap.

Thanks in advance.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.main-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slides-outer {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="slides-outer">

    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="mySlides">
        <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
        <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
        <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
        <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
    </div>

    <div class="dot-container">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.main-wrap`. Updated snippet:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.main-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides-outer {
  border-radius: 15px;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="slides-outer">

    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="mySlides">
        <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
        <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
        <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
        <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

    </div>

    <div class="dot-container">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```